# How to display error marker icon on the form editor tab in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, marker

I have seen in Eclipse IDE  while programming, when there is a compile error in a java file, Eclipse displays error icon on the tab. (Please refer image). Similarly, I have created my custom form editor and I want to display same error icon on the editor tab when there is a validation error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the editor image by calling the `WorkbenchPart`

```java
protected void setTitleImage(Image titleImage)
```

method. Your main editor part should be able to do this (editor parts extend `EditorPart` which extends `WorkbenchPart`).

It is up to you to determine when to display the error indicator and to construct the image.

JFace provides the `DecorationOverlayIcon` class which helps to overlay error indicators on a base image. For example:

```java
Image image = ... base image

ImageDescriptor overlay = ... image descriptor for overlay

DecorationOverlayIcon decoratedImageDesc = new DecorationOverlayIcon(image, overlay, IDecoration.BOTTOM_LEFT);

Image overlayedImage = decoratedImageDesc.createImage();
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Greg-449. Your answer is very helpful.